# R shiny: read ECONNRESET Error randomly occurs

Tags: r, shiny, econnreset

Almost the time the app works find but the error occurs randomly, and I cannot find the error trace in the apps log(/var/log/shiny-server):

```
An error has occurred
The application exited unexpectedly.
read ECONNRESET
```

The sessionInfo() is as below:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3
```

And there's not much info about this issue with R shiny app, maybe it's about node.js?
Thanks for any advise in advance.

Comment: You might want to include your `sessionInfo()` and a reproducible example of your app. Did you update all your packages, R / RStudio?

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/246)

Comment: @SeGa: Yes I did, but I still cannot figure out.

Comment: @TonioLiebrand: I deployed apps with shiny server and it randomly occurs errors, but it work fine locally.  I can provide my `sessionInfo()` tomorrow, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Samoth, I think you are unlikely to get much help with *something* reproducible. Some of us (many?) have the ability to host a shiny app on their own server (shinyapps.io, shiny server, or rstudio connect, for instance) and try to drill down to the problem. However, without a sample app with the appropriate "something" that causes a failure, we can test nothing. (If it's just a "hello world" app that eventually breaks on your server, then I suggest you provide `hello_world.R`. Not too much, though, please.)

Comment: @r2evans: I'd like to but my app connect to DB which is in my company. Is it still possible to come up with the minimal reproducible code? Thanks so much for your reply and advise.

Comment: You don't have to share *that app*. Can you make a minimal app that still times-out and presents that error? It might take some time (make a version, let it set ... no error, then add DB-connection, let it set ... no error, add something else). The point is that we have no idea what your app looks like, so we cannot replicate anything *close* to yours. So you don't have to do anything, but ... with nothing to look at, it's unlikely somebody will spontaneously come up with something close to yours (and likely that your bounty will go un-awarded).

Comment: @r2evans: OK let me think how to make a minimal app; the most difficult part is that this error occurs randomly, so I don't know whether the minimal example can reproduce the error or not. But I'll give it a try, thanks for your time.

Comment: I understand completely, I've had problems like that in the past (and still do, frankly). In this case, if nobody else says *"I know how to reproduce that"*, then the onus is on you, unfortunately. Good luck, we're all counting on you :-)

Comment: Sounds like a cryptic error, you might try upgrading Shiny Server as well?  They put out fairly regular patches.  You could also try swapping to a different version of R and trying that out.  You could also try adding logging to your application, this might help pinpoint the general area in the code where it's failing.  Good luck.

Comment: @firefly2442: Thanks for your reply. Actually I use docker Shiny server image to deploy apps, is it possible to upgrade Shiny server for my case?

Comment: You probably have the latest.  I guess you can always run something like `docker-compose build --pull` to make sure you grab the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by adding below code in **server.r**

```
onStop(function() {
  odbcClose(conn)
})
```

I query data from database frequently but I did not close it.
After adding the code to close connection the error seldom occurs.

And I also adjust the `app_idle_timeout` to 0 in the `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`